# Chromebook - How do I access /dev/hidraw0 in linux terminal without rooting?

Tags: chrome, chrome-book, chrome-os

As my study, hidraw device is hidden from /dev in the Chromebook. Is it possible to access or list the device ( such as stylus) without rooting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By "Linux terminal" I assume you mean the one running in the Linux VM (also known as "Linux Beta" or "Crostini"). That VM doesn't have access to hidraw nodes for security reasons (as that could allow a malicious program in the VM to intercept your keyboard or mouse input to other applications, for example).

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could try using [WebHID](https://web.dev/hid/) from a Web application.